# Add a class to an element's classList at a certain position

Tags: javascript, html

Can I add a class to certain position, to keep some order since it contradicts with some logic that targets the class by its position ?

```js
link.closest('item').classList.add('c-class')

// Contradicton We need (a-class) insted I get (c-class) that has been added
let getThisClass = e.target.parentElement.classList[1]
```

```html
<!-- before adding -->
<li class="item aclass bclass" id="60fe102d6e87274484dd2785"></li>
<!-- after adding -->
<li class="item c-class a-class b-class" id="60fe102d6e87274484dd2785"></li>
```

Comment: You can get list of all classes, order them as you want, then reassign them (similarly to the answer of @Spectric)

Comment: Creating a dependency on the order or position of tokens in a classList ([*DOMTokenList*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#domtokenlist)) does not seem like a good idea, it seems like a recipe for hard to find bugs. It's probably more appropriate to use a [*data\** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 5):

You can try splitting the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) by spaces, inserting an item at a certain position of the resulting array (with the use of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) and reassigning back to the `className` after joining by spaces:

```js
const link = document.getElementById("60fe102d6e87274484dd2785");
list = link.className.split(" ");
list.splice(1, 0, "c-class")
link.className = list.join(" ");
console.log(link.className);
```

```html
<!-- before adding -->
<li class="item aclass bclass" id="60fe102d6e87274484dd2785"></li>
```

As a generic function:

```js
const link = document.getElementById("60fe102d6e87274484dd2785");
insertClassAtPosition(link, "c-class", 1);
console.log(link.className);

function insertClassAtPosition(element, className, index){
  let l = element.className.split(" ");
  l.splice(index, 0, className);
  element.className = l.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<!-- before adding -->
<li class="item aclass bclass" id="60fe102d6e87274484dd2785"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// get the link
const link = document.getElementById("link");

// get the item
const item = link.closest('.item');

// append c-class
item.className += ' c-class';
console.log(item.className);

// remove c-class
item.className = item.className.replace(/c-class/,'').trim();
console.log(item.className);
```

```html
<!-- before adding -->
<li class="item a-class b-class" id="60fe102d6e87274484dd2785"><a id="link">#</a></li>
```